# 500.19 Internal Server Error - RequestFilteringModule config error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I'm working on a site built on the [Telligent Community](http://telligent.com) platform. It comes with a zip of the site that I need to setup and build from. I've setup the site and have been working on it, except the default `web.config` has one thing that breaks the site, unless I comment it out. The line is `<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />` in the following section:

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
  </security>
  ... continues ...
```

If I comment out the line, my site works. If not, I get this error:

```
Config Error
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
```

One thing I read was to go to `applicationHost.config` file located in `windows\system32\inetsrv\config` and change the following values in `<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">` to "Allow":

```
<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

I've made the above changes and done an `iisreset` and I still get the same error. Does anyone have any ideas that will allow this line in my config to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd actually want to check `applicationHost.config` (and possibly `machine.config`) and verify this is set: `<section name="requestFiltering" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`

Comment: Wow. How did I not even think to search for that in applicationHost? Thanks! All good.